# Multiple XEditable Select2 elements with different dynamically loaded lists: only the first URL data-source is bound

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

I have the following which binds multiple anchor elements with the class 'team' to be x-editable select2 inputs. Each a.team has a different data-source (differing on the ID passed to the Web service so that the applicable list of teams is returned), but unfortunately, once the first a.team is bound, that data-source URL is used for all subsequent a.team inputs on the page (and therefore, the wrong list of teams is bound to each subsequent x-editable select2 input).

Is it possible to "reset" the data property of the select2 so that it respects each data-source for each a.team element? Or any other solutions?

```
$('a.team').editable({
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST'
    },
    emptytext: 'TBD',
    placement: 'bottom',
    success: function (response, newValue) {
        return editableResponse(response, newValue);
    },
    select2: {
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Select a team',
        width: '200px',
        id: function (item) {
            return item.id;
        },
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data };
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Multiple a.team anchors on a page like the following:

```
  <a href="#" class="ur-team label label-inverse" data-type="select2" data-pk="@match.Id" data-source="@Url.Action("GetTeams", "Teams", new { scheduleId = match.ScheduleId })" data-value="@match.AwayTeamId" data-text="@match.AwayTeam" data-name="away" data-title="Update away team" data-url="@Url.Action("UpdateTeam", "AdminMatches")">@match.AwayTeam</a>
```

Note: I have verified that only the ID from the first x-editable select2 input is used for all other select2 AJAX calls. In other words, it is not a data caching issue (it's a "once its bound, all other data-source references are ignored" issue).

UPDATE: Here's a quick and dirty fiddle that replicates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ovalsquare/k9b3d/8/ . Note that both end up being bound to the list2 instead of list and then list2.

Comment: Would it be possible to demonstrate this issue in a `Fiddle`?

Comment: What a concept ;-) Quickly put one together that replicates the issue (see update). I can think of several workarounds, but none of them are appealing when there could be something simpler (i.e. I'm missing something obvious).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is one of the work around's that you have already thought of or how this might affect the performance in your application.  But Initializing each `.team` element individually works.

I'm going to look into a little more to see if I can find a better way to do it, but here is the current solution:

```
$('a.team').each(function(){
    $(this).editable({
        ajaxOptions: {
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST'
        },
        emptytext: 'TBD',
        placement: 'bottom',
        success: function (response, newValue) {
            return editableResponse(response, newValue);
        },
        select2: {
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: 'Select a team',
            width: '200px',
            id: function (item) {
                return item.id;
            },
            ajax: {
                dataType: 'json',
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            },
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/k9b3d/11/

A better work around would be to initialize `editable` without the source data attribute:

```
<a href="#" class="team" data-type="select2" data-pk="1" data-getSource="/list" data-value="100" data-text="Team A" data-name="home" data-title="Update home team" data-url="/post">Team A</a>
```

And then add it after initialization for every `.team` by setting the source via `option`:

```
$('a.team').each(function(){
    $(this).editable('option','source',$(this).data('getSource'));
});
```

But unfortunately it does not work when setting the `source` this way..  The best solution I could find is the one above.

Looks like there are a couple of bugs with X-editable here:

When initializing multiple select editables with different `sources`. And setting the source with the `option` method.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - especially over the holidays. Your "better work around" was one option I was considering, and your experiment showed that my best other option wouldn't work either. I'll run with the .each solution and post it up to x-editable issues. Thanks again for your input.